# How can i do this using a Python Regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to properly extract *methods* definitions that are generated by comtypes for Com Interfaces using a regex. Furthermore some of them are blank which causes even more problems for me.

Basically i have this:

```
IXMLSerializerAlt._methods_ = [
    COMMETHOD([helpstring(u'Loads an object from an XML string.')], HRESULT, 'LoadFromString',
              ( ['in'], BSTR, 'XML' ),
              ( ['in'], BSTR, 'TypeName' ),
              ( ['in'], BSTR, 'TypeNamespaceURI' ),
              ( ['retval', 'out'], POINTER(POINTER(IUnknown)), 'obj' )),
]

class EnvironmentManager(CoClass):
    u'Singleton object that manages different environments (collections of configuration information).'
    _reg_clsid_ = GUID('{8A626D49-5F5E-47D9-9463-0B802E9C4167}')
    _idlflags_ = []
    _typelib_path_ = typelib_path
    _reg_typelib_ = ('{5E1F7BC3-67C5-4AEE-8EC6-C4B73AAC42ED}', 1, 0)

INumberFormat._methods_ = [
]
```

I want to extract both the IXMLSerializerAlt and INumberFormat methods definitions however i cant figure out a proper regex. E.g. for IXMLSerializer i want to extract this:

```
IXMLSerializerAlt._methods_ = [
    COMMETHOD([helpstring(u'Loads an object from an XML string.')], HRESULT, 'LoadFromString',
              ( ['in'], BSTR, 'XML' ),
              ( ['in'], BSTR, 'TypeName' ),
              ( ['in'], BSTR, 'TypeNamespaceURI' ),
              ( ['retval', 'out'], POINTER(POINTER(IUnknown)), 'obj' )),
]
```

This regex in my mind this should work:

```
^\w+\._methods_\s=\s\[$
(^.+$)*
^]$
```

Im checking my regex's using kodos however i cannot figure out a way to make this work.

Comment: You regexp contains dollars at invalid places, like at the end of its first line, so it can't match. Another issue is that the square brackets are nested in the above syntax, so it is not easy to accomplish using a single regexp.

Comment: @fviktor: Dollars can come anywhere if multi-line matching (the `m` or `re.MULTILINE` flag) is enabled - the dollar matches at end of lines. As for nested square brackets, he's opting for a not-quite-perfect solution that simply matches until a closing square bracket alone on a line.

Comment: I know that it is not your exact question, but wouldn't it be easier to extract this information from `comtypes` directly without parsing the interface definitions?

Comment: Max: Thanks for your comment on the dollars and `re.MULTILINE`, I always learn something new. :)

Comment: @fviktor Not really, i'm just doing this to test something quickly, since comtypes is not generating certain things properly.

Comment: @uberjumper: Ok, I see. See my solution below, that tries to account for nested [ ] pairs up to one level. I guess the interface definitions do not contain more deeply nested pairs of square brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the newline characters between `$` and `^`, and may not be using the `re.MULTILINE` flag which allows those to anchor at the start and end of lines. The following (compiled with `re.MULTILINE`) would match:

```
\w+\._methods_\s=\s\[$(?:\n^.+$)*\n^\]$
```

However, here's a slightly simpliifed regex that will also match your examples:

```
>>> s = '''...\nIXMLSerializerAlt._methods_ = [\n    COMMETHOD([helpstring(u'Loads an object from an XML string.')], HRESULT, 'LoadFromString',\n              ( ['in'], BSTR, 'XML' ),\n              ( ['in'], BSTR, 'TypeName' ),\n              ( ['in'], BSTR, 'TypeNamespaceURI' ),\n              ( ['retval', 'out'], POINTER(POINTER(IUnknown)), 'obj' )),\n]\n...'''
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'^\w+\._methods_\s=\s\[$.*?^\]$', s, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
["IXMLSerializerAlt._methods_ = [\n    COMMETHOD([helpstring(u'Loads an object from an XML string.')], HRESULT, 'LoadFromString',\n              ( ['in'], BSTR, 'XML' ),\n              ( ['in'], BSTR, 'TypeName' ),\n              ( ['in'], BSTR, 'TypeNamespaceURI' ),\n              ( ['retval', 'out'], POINTER(POINTER(IUnknown)), 'obj' )),\n]"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

interface_definitions = '''
IXMLSerializerAlt._methods_ = [
    COMMETHOD([helpstring(u'Loads an object from an XML string.')], HRESULT, 'LoadFromString',
              ( ['in'], BSTR, 'XML' ),
              ( ['in'], BSTR, 'TypeName' ),
              ( ['in'], BSTR, 'TypeNamespaceURI' ),
              ( ['retval', 'out'], POINTER(POINTER(IUnknown)), 'obj' )),
]

class EnvironmentManager(CoClass):
    u'Singleton object that manages different environments (collections of configuration information).'
    _reg_clsid_ = GUID('{8A626D49-5F5E-47D9-9463-0B802E9C4167}')
    _idlflags_ = []
    _typelib_path_ = typelib_path
    _reg_typelib_ = ('{5E1F7BC3-67C5-4AEE-8EC6-C4B73AAC42ED}', 1, 0)

INumberFormat._methods_ = [
]
'''

RX_METHODS = re.compile(
    r'(\w+)\._methods_\s=\s\[('
    r'.*?'
    r'(?:\[.*?\].*?)*'
    r')\]',
    re.DOTALL)

for match in RX_METHODS.finditer(interface_definitions):
    print match.groups()
```